# While loop - contador de números menos 0

Tags: javascript, while

boa noite!

Preciso aplicar um loop para o usuário sempre digitar um número (via prompt), quando digitar 0 deve aparecer um alert informando a quantidade de números digitados, sem contar o zero.

Não estou entendendo o que estou fazendo de errado, pois ele está apresentando um alert com todos os números digitados, incluindo o zero.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer para contar apenas a quantidade de números excluindo o zero?

Obrigado.

```
function TESTE2() {

        var number = prompt("Enter a number, 0 to stop: ");
        var result = 0;

        while (number !== 0){
            result = result+number;
            number = +prompt("Enter another, chose 0 to stop");
            }

        while (number == 0){
            alert("You entered "+ result+ " non-zero numbers!");
            break;
            }           
    }
```

Comment: Queres somar os numeros assim (https://jsfiddle.net/r4dbybLd/)  ou queres texto com os numeros todos?

Comment: Quase isso, só que não quero somar os números digitados, quero somar a quantidade de números digitados. Por exemplo, se digitar 10, 7, 8 e 0 não quero somar 10 + 7 + 8, quero somar e mostrar que digitei 3 números antes do 0

Comment: Podes explicar o contexto em que precisas desta funcionalidade? para alem do alert onde vais usar o que a função cria?

Comment: Pelo que entendi o seu problema esta acontecendo porque vc digital 0 no primeiro prompt e mesmo assim entra no loop.
existe varias maneiras de resolver isso,
uma delas é removendo o segundo = de !== deixando assim !=
isso esta acontecendo porque nas linguagens de programação o terceiro comparador serve para comparar tambem o tipo da variavel, no seu exemplo
a variavel number na verdade nao é do tipo numero, pois o prompt retorna uma string Porem tambem creio que vc havera tambem outro problema
pois no texto você fala que quer somar os numero digitados, isso nao esta muito claro. Mas no seu exe

Answer (score 1):

Basta fazer assim:

```
(function () {
    var number = prompt("Enter a number, 0 to stop: ");
    var quantity = 0;

    while (number != 0) {
        quantity++;
        number = Number(prompt("Enter another, chose 0 to stop"));
    }

    alert("You entered " + quantity + " non-zero numbers!");
}());
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Ajudou bastante, substitui o !==0 pelo !=0. Ainda estou tentando entender o Javascript. Se eu quisesse ao invés de somar todos os resultados menos 0, quisesse separar os números positivos dos negativos, excluindo o 0, como ficaria? Por exemplo, digitei 1, 2, -3 e 0. "Vc digitou 2 numeros positivos e 1 negativo". Não sei se estou complicando demais, mas tô tentando pegar o raciocínio.

Comment: Ficaria assim:

`(function () {
    var number = prompt("Enter a number, 0 to stop: ");
    var positiveQuantity = 0, negativeQuantity = 0;

    while (number !== 0) {
        if (number < 0) {
            negativeQuantity++;
        } else {
            positiveQuantity++;
        }
        
        quantity++;
        number = Number(prompt("Enter another, chose 0 to stop"));
    }

    alert("You typed: " + quantity + " numbers, " + negativeQuantity + " negatives and " + positiveQuantity + " positives");
}());`

Answer (score 1):

podes usar uma `array`, fazer o `push` sempre que o valor não for 0 e, no final, retornar o `length` da `array`:

```
var numbers = [];

function loopPrompt() {
  var input = prompt('Number? [0 escapes]');

  if (!input || parseInt(input,10) === 0) {
    alert(numbers.length + ' numbers were inserted: ' + numbers.toString());
    return;
  }

  numbers.push(input);
  loopPrompt();
}

loopPrompt();
```

Answer (score 1):

creio que no exemplo de hpedrorodrigues resolve seu problema porem
trocando !== por != o motivo comentei antes

```js
(function () {
    var number = prompt("Enter a number, 0 to stop: ");
    var quantity = 0;

    while (number != 0) {
        quantity++;
        number = Number(prompt("Enter another, chose 0 to stop"));
    }

    alert("You entered " + quantity + " non-zero numbers!");
}());
```

Comment: Se eu quisesse ao invés de somar todos os resultados menos 0, quisesse separar os números positivos dos negativos, excluindo o 0, como ficaria? Por exemplo, digitei 1, 2, -3 e 0. "Vc digitou 2 numeros positivos e 1 negativo". Não sei se estou complicando demais, mas tô tentando pegar o raciocínio.